# ASP.NET CheckBoxField - setting value question

Tags: c#, asp.net

I trying to pass some values that the user selects but I am unable to set the CheckBoxField in my gridview.

Could someone please let me know how to do this?

Here is my code so far...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" SkinID="CompacGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" Width="400px" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" 
                                BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                                GridLines="Vertical">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <Columns>


                    <asp:CheckBoxField headertext="mm" />
```

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, Microsoft omitted the 'Value' property from its specification for CheckBox in ASP.NET, despite it being a [completely valid feature of HTML](http://devsushi.com/2007/07/16/aspnet-checkboxes-should-be-able-to-have-values/). My guess is that they wanted it to be as similar to the WinForms CheckBox as possible (which also lacks a 'Value' property).

If you want to give your `<asp:CheckBox />` or `<asp:CheckBoxField />` a 'Value' property you will either have to extend the control yourself and define a custom 'Value' property, or make use of the code-behind to populate the Attributes or InputAttributes collection of the control. [See this article for more details](http://www.daveparslow.com/2007/08/assigning-value-to-aspnet-checkbox.html).

```
cbMyCheckBoxField.Attributes.Add("Value", "foo");
```

or

```
cbMyCheckBoxField.InputAttributes.Add("Value", "foo");
```

The main difference between these two approaches is that the former will **not** include the Value in the generated HTML (only ViewState), while the latter will.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that out. Now I have to figure out how I populate the value with a datafield from the datasource within each row.

Comment: Not a perfect solution but I use tooltip attribute. its easier to access than Attributes or InputAttributes.

Comment: lol. wow. every day webforms finds new ways to suprise and disgust me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `DataField` attribute based on a boolean condition on the datasource object. It appears you're binding to an ObjectDataSource. Perhaps there's a boolean condition on the class -- say it's `IsHired`.

Perhaps something like:

```
     <asp:CheckBoxField headertext="mm" DataField="IsHired" />
```

There's a sample on the [MSDN CheckBoxField article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I dont have a boolean flag in my datasource. Thank you for your quick help.

Comment: @Steve: what are you looking for then? It's not clear in your question what work/task you have, or what your desired output is.

Comment: I need to pass an ID field that I have in the datasource but the checkbox only allows me to use a boolean. In classic ASP I was able to pass any value I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Nathan's answer:  I would use the RowDataBound event for your GridView.  Assuming you bound to a DataTable, with the interesting column being [0].

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Check for a data row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the checkbox control by ID and set it.
        ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoxId")).Checked = IsItemChecked(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)[0]);
    } 
}
```

The IsItemChecked function can be passed the data from the DataItem to create custom logic that passes back a boolean.  Once you have the control, you can also add attributes to it.  This is a powerful technique once you master it.

Comment: This looks promising but I am getting this error:
The name 'IsItemChecked' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Hey Steve, sorry for the delay in my response.  You need to create the IsItemChecked method.  Inside it you will put the logic to return a boolean that indicates the check box status.